# List all the tags from a post under custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm looking for solution that will display all the tags that are used on a custom post type. I just want to list them all because I'm going to add jQuery code on each tag. :)

I try use `<?php the_tags(); ?>` but not show any tags !

Comment: you should use the_terms() i guess.. also make sure to pass the taxonomy slug properly

Comment: i use it and same thing

Comment: can you share me the code how you used it?

Comment: `<?php the_tags(); ?>` and i use `<?php the_terms(); ?>`